# How to add Jquery Mobile effects to dynamically added elements?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

While working with Jquery Mobile I am facing a strange issue. Jquery Mobile adds some default classes and css to every element based upon data-role etc. when i create new elements normal css get applied to all the new generated elements , but not Jquery Mobile ?

html

```
    <ul data-role="listview" > 
        <li><a href="#">sada</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">sada</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">sada</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" class="hello" >Add</a>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.hello').click(function(){
      $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">sada</a></li> ');
})
```

check JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/sahil20grover1988/zZMXQ/2/ . Clicking on button will create new **Li** element in **LIST** How to apply JQuery Mobile features to elements

Comment: It looks to me like that jQuery side of things is applying some styling when the document is loaded, and this isn't being re-applied when new items are added. I would look at finding out how to generate the <li>'s you want, outside of just appending the html, chances are there is a specific jQuery Mobile function to do it, which will retain the styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery live function for bind new action for newly added element

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
     //do something
})
```

and you can refresh the list like this to get the list view correct,
http://jsfiddle.net/zZMXQ/13/

```
$("ul").listview("refresh");
```

Comment: Did you read his question? Did you see his jsfiddle? It has nothing to do with live

Comment: you don't have the button click event.

Comment: @Jayantha check again your fiddle - 33 not working ..... any ways I have implemented that one more thing if i want to refresh the whole content block then ???

Comment: It is not working because it can't call your URL from the fiddle.(see what happens to the URL in firebug). It shoud work in your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

you need to reload the jquery mobile list style

after appending the element

try this:

```
$("ul").listview("refresh");
```